# How to detect if browser window closed in flutter using url launcher in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using url_launcher, just want to know when the window has been closed, is there a way?
I want to do a process when the browser window closed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt functionality for that.